# Tightly curled over tail and strange gait

Tags: cats, health

Back in December my cat came in and was acting strangely, his back legs were low to the ground and his tail was curled right over like a spring onto his back. He then started walking round in a circle backwards.. As it was late at night there was nothing I could do. In the morning he had a limp and it seemed like his back legs were giving way and his tail kept curling over.

When I took him to the vets they couldn't find any problems with his bones, they gave him Metacan which he took for a week but it didn't do anything. I then took him back again and they said it might be a trapped nerve and didn't give any medication. I took him back AGAIN and they said to leave it for 2/3 months but I'm not happy to leave him like it! What do you think it could be?

I also had Ted microchipped and discovered it wasn't working after he couldn't enter the cat flap.. The vet couldn't locate it anywhere in his body so they gave him another one. Any chance the one that is 'lost' could be causing the trouble?

Comment: Thanks for your questions! If you don't mind, could you move the second question about the missing microchip as a separate question. That way it's more visible to people who might be able to answer that one question. There's more reasoning in [this Meta discussion](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/why-is-it-better-to-ask-all-my-questions-separately-and-not-all-at-once). Thanks!

Comment: Has your vet ruled out a blood clot?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong with your kitty? Our cat was acting similarly today and it freaked me out. She had her tail curled very tightly over her and stumbled around a bit. Thanks.

Comment: my cat is displaying the
same symptoms. We have also had multiple vet visits and the vets are perplexed at what it could be.
Did you ever discover what the issue was ? And did your cat recover ?

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible for us to diagnose your cat over the internet, only a fully trained veterinarian can diagnose your cat after a physical examination.

If your vet isn't taking your concerns seriously, I would recommend seeking a second opinion from another vet or requesting referral a specialist (probably neurology, but your vet would know).

Even if your vet does not know what is causing the problem, they should be able to answer questions such as

- is my pet in any pain/discomfort?
- If we let this situation continue, what signs should I look for to determine if pain/discomfort develops?
- If we let this situation continue, what signs should I look for to determine if my pet's condition is deteriorating?
- Does my pet have any special needs as a result of this condition? Does he understand his current condition, or will he try to jump to a high spot and fall, potentially worsening his condition?